# How can I insert a ContentVersion record in a test class?

Tags: unit-test, contentversion

What value do I set for the `VersionData`, `PathOnClient` and `FirstPublishLocationId` fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public ID setupContent(){ 
RecordType ContentRT = [select Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name='Sales Documents'];
 ContentVersion testContentInsert =newContentVersion(); 
 testContentInsert.ContentURL='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/';" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com/';</a> 
 testContentInsert.Title ='Google.com'; 
 testContentInsert.RecordTypeId = ContentRT.Id; 
 insert testContentInsert; 

 ContentVersion testContent = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where Id = :testContentInsert.Id]; 
 ContentWorkspace testWorkspace = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name='Opportunity Documents ']; 

 ContentWorkspaceDoc newWorkspaceDoc =newContentWorkspaceDoc(); 
 newWorkspaceDoc.ContentWorkspaceId = testWorkspace.Id; 
 newWorkspaceDoc.ContentDocumentId = testContent.ContentDocumentId; 
 insert newWorkspaceDoc;

 testContent.iPad_Content_Views__c =0; 
 update testContent;

 return testContentInsert.Id; 
   }
```

Please use this sample code to create `contentversion` in test cl ass.

Answer (score -1):

With this method the test fails

> Error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, URL must have a valid protocol: [ContentUrl]
> Adding contentUrl I get this other :
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Unable to complete operation.: []

The second error is only obtained in test classes, with execution from exsecute anonymous the DML insert works

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: This strikes me more as a comment than an answer in its own right.